# Why do I get TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'master' in Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I got:

```
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'master'
```

I don't know what's the problem. This is my code:

```
from tkinter import*
class minigame():
def __init__(self,master):
    self.master=master
    self.master.title("try")
    self.lbl1=Label(self.master)
    self.lbl1['text']="User Name"
    self.lbl1.grid(row=1,column=1)
    self.txt1=Entry(self.master)
    self.txt1['width']=30
    self.txt1.grid(row=1,column=2)
    self.b4=Button(self.master,text="start",command=mulai)
    self.b4.grid(row=2,column=2)
class mulai():
def __init__(self,master):
    self.win=master
    self.win.title('MINIGAME')
    self.asal()
def asal(self):
    self.masteer.withdraw()
    self.tk=Toplevel(self.master)
    self.radi(self.tk)
def start(self):
    self.var=IntVar()
    self.pilihan="Anda Menjawab" +str(var.get())
def radi(self):
    var=self.start
    rb1=Radiobutton(self.master,text="Martha",variable=self.var,value=0,command=self.start)
    rb1.grid(row=1)
    rb2=Radiobutton(self.master,text="Kula Diamond",variable=self.var,value=1,command=self.start)
    rb2.grid(row=2)
    self.label=Label(self.master,text="WHO IS THE BEST WAIFU?")
    self.label.grid(row=0)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root=Tk()
    app=minigame(root)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Format your code so it is readable

Comment: i alreadt edit,im sorry thats my fault this is my first time here

Comment: ***`command=mulai`***: You can't use a`class type` as a callback reference. Read up on [The Tkinter Button Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm)

Comment: Is it true? but in my other code it works

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what the problem is. When you create an instance of `minigame` or `mulai` you are required to pass in a master. That's how you've defined those classes.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.b4=Button(self.master,text="start",command=mulai)
```

you can use a function in the command, the function will launch the class, giving the root as parameter.

```
self.b4=Button(self.master,text="start",command=self.launch_mulai)

def launch_mulai(self, *arg):
   mulai(self.master)
```

Comment: it helped me, but I found a new error AttributeError: 'mulai' object has no attribute 'master'

Comment: @YenFei - You aren't defining a `property` on `mulai` called master, at least not in the code in your question. I see `minigame` has one.